# Preventing auto indentation with TexMaths in LibreOffice

Tags: indentation, libre-office

I’m using a tool called [TexMaths](http://roland65.free.fr/texmaths/index.html) to edit equations and math symbols in LibreOffice. I’m having troubles with how the extension chooses to handle indentation, and I don’t know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

An example is:

```
$\text{\bf{Definition 1.1.}}$ Alternating sign matrices (ASMs) are square matrices with the following properties:  

$\bullet$ entries $\in\{0,1,-1\}$  

$\bullet$ the entries in each row and column sum to 1  

$\bullet$ nonzero entries in each row and column alternate in sign
```

which gives me

[image]

What I’d like is something like this instead.

[image]

Comment: Why not let LibreOffice handle the indentation, and just use TexMaths to just handle the mathematical content? From what I can see (I can't see your images, as imgur is blocked by my workplace), you would only need `\in{0,1,-1}` from your first bullet to be LaTeXed. All of the other formatting can (should?) be done directly in LibreOffice.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I guess that’s also a valid option, although for more complicated statements that would involve putting a lot of images generated by TexMaths on top of the text boxes. Or is there any tricks to deal with this that I don’t know of?

Comment: Besides aligning the text and the images is a bit difficult.

Comment: No idea of using TeXMaths in LO, but I guess that you should use it only for `$\in\{0,1,-1\}$` and leave the remaining text in the hands of LO.